# How to sort and query on child collection in RavenDB?

Tags: c#, ravendb

Thank you for your help and patience.
I am still learning about RavenDB, so I ask for help with something seemingly simple, but one that beat me after many attempts and extensive research.
So decide to ask for help here ...

Given the model:

```
public class Travel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string DriverId { get; set; }
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
{

public class Driver
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
{
```

How could I sort and filter by driver name?

Strangely, linq didn't work as expected:

```
session.Query<Travel>().Include(travel => travel.DriverId)
    .OrderBy(travel => travel.Driver.Name);
```

The line above emanates the following RQL:

```
from Travels order by Driver.Name include DriverId
```

Which seemed correct, but for some reason, either with Linq or RQL, the travel list is not sorted by driver name.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your include statement to be include(travel => travel.Driver).

Comment: Thank you, but [RavenDB](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/csharp/client-api/how-to/handle-document-relationships#includes) docs says that the syntax for the Include statement has to be done with the Id field like so:

`IList<Order> orders = session.Query<Order>().Include(o => o.CustomerId).Where(x => x.TotalPrice > 100).ToList();

foreach (Order order in orders)
{
    // this will not require querying the server!
    Customer customer = session.Load<Customer>(order.CustomerId);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add ToList? I was able to successfully get a list of travels ordered by driver names.

```
session.Query<Travel>().Include(travel => travel.DriverId)
       .OrderBy(travel => travel.Driver.Name)
       .ToList();
```